# javascript should return false, form still validates and php inserts data in table

Tags: php, javascript, forms, validation

Hello and many thanks in advance to everybody that will read and answer this post. 
First of all I am awfully sorry if this has already been answered but I am looking for an answer to this for like 12h on the whole web and nothing that i found worked out. 
So my issue is as follows: i have a form, a script and a php part. as the webpage will have many form pages i tried to write the script so that i gets the data it needs to validate directly from the fields. therefore the function has an argument. now, the submit button is hidden and i am using enter after the final field to automatically submit the form. even if the javascript works (it creates a red border around the fields that are empty), when i press enter the form still submits through php. in my noobiness i think that the problem is that either the script doesnt return true or false or that the onSubmit has an error therefore it doesnt get passed true of false. i am posting the codes bellow. 
many thanks, once again!

for the form part:

```
        <form action="addUser.php" method="post" name="login" onsubmit="return checkField()">

          <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="addUser">
            <tr>
              <td><p class="capRegister">Date de utilizator</p></td>
              <td><p class="capRegister">Date de identificare</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input class="input1" name="user" type="text" placeholder="alege-ti un nume de utilizator" tabindex="1" onblur="checkField(name)" value="<?php echo $user; ?>"/></td>
              <td><input class="input1" name="nume" type="text" placeholder="numele tau" tabindex="4" onblur="checkField(name)" value="<?php echo $nume ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input class="input1" name="password" type="password" placeholder="alege-ti o parola" tabindex="2" onblur="checkField(name)" /></td>
              <td><input class="input1" name="prenume" type="text" placeholder="prenumele tau" tabindex="5" onblur="checkField(name)" value="<?php echo $prenume; ?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td><input class="input1" name="confirma" type="password" placeholder="confirma parola" tabindex="3" onblur="checkField(name)" /></td>
              <td><input class="input1" name="interior" type="tel" placeholder="interior" tabindex="6" onblur="checkField(name)" value="<?php echo $interior ?>"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><input class="input1" name="mobil" type="tel" placeholder="mobil" tabindex="7" onblur="checkField(name)" value="<?php echo $mobil; ?>"/></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <p><input class="submitButton" name="login2" type="submit" value="" /></p>

  </form>
```

now for the script part:

```
function checkField(x) {

//initializeaza o variabila care pe baza argumentului functiei verifica campurile dupa nume (argumentul contine numele campului)
var continutCamp=document.getElementsByName(x)[0].value;
//variabila pentru footer
var msgJos;
//variabila pentru parola
var tempParola=document.getElementsByName('password')[0].value; 

msgJos="";
document.getElementById('bottomBar').innerHTML=msgJos;
document.getElementsByName(x)[0].style.borderStyle='none';

//verifica daca campul este gol     
if (continutCamp==null || continutCamp=="")
    {   
    // inconjoara cu o margine rosie eroarea
    document.getElementsByName(x)[0].style.borderColor='#FF0000';
    document.getElementsByName(x)[0].style.borderStyle='solid';
    document.getElementsByName(x)[0].style.borderRadius='4px';

    // scrie un mesaj in campul de jos

    msgJos='<p id="footerInfo">nu ai completat campul '+ x +'</p>';
    document.getElementById('bottomBar').innerHTML=msgJos;

    //return false pentru a impiedica procesarea formularului
    return false;

    }

        //daca nu se potriveste parola cu confirmarea
if((name=="confirma")&&(continutCamp!=tempParola))
{
    //coloreaza ambele campuri de parola si confirmare cu rosu
    document.getElementsByName('confirma')[0].style.borderColor='#FF0000';
    document.getElementsByName('confirma')[0].style.borderStyle='solid';
    document.getElementsByName('confirma')[0].style.borderRadius='4px';
    document.getElementsByName('password')[0].style.borderColor='#FF0000';
    document.getElementsByName('password')[0].style.borderStyle='solid';
    document.getElementsByName('password')[0].style.borderRadius='4px';

    //cod ca sa schimbe continutul footerului cu mesajul potrivit
    msgJos='<p id="footerInfo">parolele nu se potrivesc</p>';
    document.getElementById('bottomBar').innerHTML=msgJos;

    //din nou return false ca sa nu se proceseze formularul daca parola nu e aceeasi
return false;
}


}
```

and finally the php part:

```
<?php
require_once("localVars.php");

$footerError;

if(isset($_POST['user']))
{

// $dbc=mysqli_connect(USER,PASS,BAZA) or die ('<p id="footerInfo"> Eroare in timp ce ma conectam </p>');

$user=$_POST['user'];
$parola=$_POST['password'];
$nume=$_POST['nume'];
$prenume=$_POST['prenume'];
$interior=$_POST['interior'];
$mobil=$_POST['mobil'];

$query="INSERT INTO users (user, parola, nume, prenume, interior, mobil) VALUES ('$user','$parola','$nume','$prenume','$interior','$mobil')"; 

// $result=mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die ('<p id="footerInfo"> Eroare in timp ce bagam datele </p>');

mysqli_close($dbc); 
}

else{

    $footerError='nu sunt date de introdus';
}

?>
```

the php has comments on it in order not to send the billion tries in the database. the $_POST checks for user but it did check for submit or any other field name before.

Comment: Your `checkField()` method expects an argument x but you not passing anything in your `onsubmit`. I would start there.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `checkField(x)` is expecting a variable 'x', but your onSubmit listener only has "`return checkField()`" which is missing the expected variable.  It's a javascript error, and since it can't evaluate and return true/false to the form, the form is submitted.

In case you don't already have it, download firebug (getfirebug.com) and install it in your browser, it will make debugging these kinds of javascript errors really easy.

Comment: thank you all for your fast reply. however, i used to have an argument there. when it did, it was written like checkField(name). and it didnt validate the form not even when all the fields were correctly filled. that's why i removed the argument from there. it might be that the argument was not correct but i dont know what argument to call in there to have it return false or true

Comment: We're talking about two different things here.  One is a logic problem, the other is a javascript syntax problem.  If the `checkField` function is expecting a variable (regardless of what it's called), a variable must be passed to it or it will error out.

Comment: any argument i try in there except for the actual name ends in validating the form. if i write name it will never under no circumstance validate the form. so something is awfully wrong

Comment: @RazvanSoneriu and that's the other side of the coin.  The way that you are attempting to validate this form is flawed.  Once you fix the javascript syntax, you still need to write the code so it works logically.

Comment: well i thpought my logic was fine. all im trying to accomplish is to get the name of the field from the field itself and not write the case for each field as the webapplication will have many fields to check and i need something that works for all cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem appears to be that you are using the global variable 'name' when there is no such variable.  Hence your onblur events do not call the function correctly.  `name` is not synonymous with `this`.  If you want to get the name of the element that the event is firing on, you'll have to instead replace `name` with `this.name`:

```
<input class="input1" name="password" type="password" placeholder="alege-ti o parola" tabindex="2" onblur="checkField(this.name)" />
```

**UPDATE:**

Another problem is that you do a check on the variable `name` yet again, without that variable existing.  Replace `name` with `x` here:

```
if((name=="confirma")&&(continutCamp!=tempParola))
```

So it looks like

```
if((x=="confirma")&&(continutCamp!=tempParola))
```

That should be it, I tested it on my end before editing this answer.

Comment: i will definitely try this! many many thanks, will return with an answer shortly

Comment: this still doesnt work. so the issue is if the function automatically gets the field name (hence is applicable universally to any field) what should it do when the name is login, so that it returns true or false.

Comment: many thanks! but i actually created a new function to be called when submitting the form, which checks if all the fields are filled.